# Filtering elements by tagName

Tags: javascript, json

**[Example Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7Lvxnsvu/3/)**.

I need to add conditions so my code support inputs (1 button need to generate the whole Json).

I've tried filtering with :

```
elements.tagName
```

But it gives me an undefined, I suppose it is because

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('selectVal');
```

Returns a nodelist. How can I filter or adapt my code so the same function supports inputs?

I need to storage the selected item in list and the strings in the inputs just with one button.

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('.selectVal, input')`

Comment: While a JSFiddle is nice, your code needs to be in the question. Please [edit] your question to include the code.

Comment: Adding input to the selector won't help by itself. You need to check what type of element when looping the elements to get values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`elements` is the array of elements you get from `getElementsByClassName`. You should check tagName on `elements[index]` inside the loop instead.

Add the input (replace the `selectVal` with a better class to all form objects though):

```
<input id="textbox" class="selectVal" value="text value">
```

You can change the inner part of the loop to look for the tag

```
...
var strSel = '';
if (element.tagName == 'SELECT')
    strSel = element.options[element.selectedIndex].text;
else if (element.tagName == 'INPUT')
    strSel = element.value;
...
```

Comment: Just a simple correction, 'select' and 'input' need to be uppercase to work.

Comment: @Pablo Corrected. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As @adeneo mentioned in the above comment you could use `querySelectorAll` with multiple selector separated by comma `,` To get the `.selectVal` and `input` values :

```
document.querySelectorAll('.selectVal, input');
```

Hope this helps.

```js
function getSelectedItems(){
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.selectVal, input')

  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var element = elements[i];

    if (element.tagName==='SELECT')
      console.log(element.options[element.selectedIndex].text);
    else
      console.log(element.value);
  }
}
```

```html
<select id="Sobre" class="selectVal">
  <option value="1" selected>fasfaf</option>
  <option value="2">afsaf</option>
  <option value="3">Fraasfsafe</option>
</select>

<select id="asdafa" class="selectVal">
  <option value="1">fassad</option>
  <option value="2" selected>fasfsa</option>
  <option value="3">asdasf</option>
</select>

<select id="asdf" class="selectVal">
  <option value="1">fdsa</option>
  <option value="2">asdfg</option>
  <option value="3" selected>dsaf</option>
</select>

<input name="test" value='input value' />
<button onClick="getSelectedItems()">Añadir</button>
```

Comment: var strSel = element.options[element.selectedIndex].text; is giving me undefined with this solution, wonder why?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know an elegant way of filtering the list other than using something like jQuery. You might be stuck with an old school solution:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('selectVal');
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i) {
    var element = elements[i];
    if (i.tagName == 'DIV') {
        // whatever
    }
}
```

That said, this will find you all the `<div>`s of class `selectVal`:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('div.selectVal');
```

That might be enough depending on your use case.